# How to have a common base type for domain classes in GORM GRAILS?

Tags: hibernate, grails-orm

If i have something like...

```
class Tiger{
    int id
    String name
}

class Giraffe{
    int id
    String name
}
```

How can i have it so they extend from a common class e.g. Animal but i dont need an Animals table, only Giraffe and Tiger tables
So i would like to be able to queries like Animal.findNameBy('Bob')
Is this doable in GORM?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a class `Animal` in `grails-app/src/java` or `grails-app/src/groovy` and then your domains can extend that class and its members to use in your `Giraffe` and `Tiger` domains.

I don't think you can use GORM queries on the `Animal` class though. 
Give it a try and find out.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is easily possible. Just do it, as you have described: Add a class animal in your domain folder and let giraffe and tiger derive from this class. Everything will work as desired immediately, so that you can query all your animals from the `Anmial` class. Have a look at: http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/5.%20Object%20Relational%20Mapping%20%28GORM%29.html#5.2.3%20Inheritance%20in%20GORM

Please remove the `int id` definition, since GORM will handle your id`s.

You can have one table per hierarchy or per subclass. Have a look at: http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/5.%20Object%20Relational%20Mapping%20%28GORM%29.html#5.5.2.3%20Inheritance%20Strategies

Answer (score 1):

This will generate a Tiger table and a Giraffe table that both have (in addition to the default GORM id and version columns) a column labeled Name. While Giraffe will also have a column labeled spots, and Tiger will have a column labeled stripes.

```
class Animal{
  String name
  static mapping = {
    tablePerHierarchy false
   }
}

class Tiger{
  String stripes
}

class Giraffe{
  String spots
}
```